# Mail Message total size limit in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, mailmessage

I'm using System.Net.Mail and MailMessage to put together emails with attachments and send using SmtpClint but I have a email limit of 19mb.

I have a simple form with a number of textboxes or dropdowns and 3 possible attachments, I tested adding a single 18mb attachment but got a mail undeliverable response saying that the message was 24mb large.

So far no matter what I search I can only find information about mail attachments rather than the mail message as a whole so if push comes to shove I'll just add some code to check each attachment size, add em up then make sure they're all under 14/15mb total.

Any ideas/suggestions/links would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure this has been answered before, so I'll comment: attachments are ~ 33% larger in transmit than their size on disk because of the way they are encoded. So your limit will be ~14 MB.

Comment: and have you access to male server? can you change config there?

Comment: @teovankot Nope I can't change the mail server config which was why I was looking for a way to check the whole email size in the hopes that I could validate that in the post and throw an error if it's too large.